# XML Parsing error in Swift

Tags: ios, xml, swift

I'm trying to "modernize" one of our apps that takes XML data from NOAA.  The existing app, using this "simple XML to NSDictionary converter" (http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/) works like a champ.  Because it works and because I'm aiming for the rebuilt app to be converted to Swift as much as possible, I attempted a faithful conversion of that XML to NSDictionary code.  Unfortunately, I'm getting **NSXMLParserErrorLineNumber=1, NSXMLParserErrorColumn=47, NSXMLParserErrorMessage=Space required after the Public Identifier**.

The URL of the XML source is http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?FcstType=digitalDWML&lat=40.501368&lon=-79.865723  I'd love to skip the XML option just to avoid the headaches, but NOAA's not consistent with what it presents in the different data formats (DWML, XML, JSON).

Any ideas where I'm messing up?

The code that calls the object below is:

```
    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Task completed")
        if(error) {
            // if there is an error in the request, print it to the console
            self.delegate?.didCompleteWithError(error.localizedDescription)
            //println(error.localizedDescription)
            println("oops!")
        }
        var err: NSError?
        if self.responseFormat == "JSON" {
            // blah blah blah ... the code here does work fine. Snipped for brevity
        } else if self.responseFormat == "XML" {
            // Put XML parsing code here
            var error = NSError()
            var xmlReader = XMLDictionary(error: error)
            var xmlResult = xmlReader.dictionaryForXMLData(data, error: error) as NSDictionary
            self.delegate?.didCompleteWithDictionary(xmlResult)
        }
```

The "XML to NSDictionary converter:

```
//
//  XMLDictionary.swift
//
//

import Foundation

class XMLDictionary: NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate {

    var dictionaryStack = NSMutableArray()

var textInProgress = ""
let XMLReaderTextNodeKey = "text"
var errorP = NSError()

func dictionaryForXMLData(data: NSData, error: NSError) -> NSDictionary {
   var reader = XMLDictionary(error: error)
    return reader.objectWithData(data, error: error) as NSDictionary
}

func dictionaryForXMLString(string: String, error: NSError) -> NSDictionary {
    var data : NSData = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    return dictionaryForXMLData(data, error: error)
}

init(error: NSError) {
    self.errorP = error
}

func objectWithData(data:NSData, error:NSError) -> NSDictionary {
    // clear out any old data
    dictionaryStack.removeAllObjects()
    textInProgress = ""

    // Initialize the stack with a fresh dictionary
    dictionaryStack.addObject(NSMutableDictionary())

    // Parse the XML
    var parser = NSXMLParser(data: data)
    parser.delegate = self

    // some more needed
    var success:Bool = parser.parse()

    if success {
        println("parse success!")
    } else {
        println("parse failure!")
    }

    // Return the stack's root dictionary on success
    var resultDict : NSDictionary! = dictionaryStack[0] as NSDictionary
    NSLog(" in parser: %@", resultDict)
    return resultDict as NSDictionary

}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!,didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName : String!, attributes attributeDict: NSDictionary!) {

    // Get the dictionary for the current level in the stack
    var elementCount = dictionaryStack.count - 1
    if elementCount < 0 {
        elementCount = 0
    }
    NSLog("element: %d", elementCount)
    var parentDict = dictionaryStack[elementCount] as NSMutableDictionary

    // Create the child dictionary for the new element and initialize it with the attributes
    var childDict = NSMutableDictionary()
    childDict.addEntriesFromDictionary(attributeDict)

    // If there's already an item for this key, it means we need to create an array
    var existingValue : AnyObject? = parentDict[elementName]! as AnyObject
    if let eValue : NSMutableArray = existingValue as? NSMutableArray {
        var array = NSMutableArray()
        if eValue.isKindOfClass(NSMutableArray) {
            // The array exists, so use it
            array = eValue
        } else {
            array.addObject(eValue)
            // Replace the child dictionary with an array of children dictionaries
            parentDict.setObject(array, forKey: elementName)
        }

        // Add the new child dictionary to the array
        array.addObject(childDict)
    } else {
        // No existing value, so update the dictionary
        parentDict.setObject(childDict, forKey: elementName)
    }

    // Update the stack
    dictionaryStack.addObject(childDict)

}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didEndElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!) {

    // Update the parent dict with text info
    var elementCount = dictionaryStack.count - 1
    if elementCount < 0 {
        elementCount = 0
    }
    var dictInProgress = dictionaryStack[elementCount] as NSMutableDictionary

    // Set the text property
    if countElements(textInProgress) > 0 {
        // Get rid of leading + trailing whitespace
        dictInProgress.setObject(textInProgress, forKey: XMLReaderTextNodeKey)

        // Reset the text
        textInProgress = ""

    }

    // Pop the current dict
    dictionaryStack.removeLastObject()

}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, foundCharacters string: String!) {
    // Build the text value
    textInProgress += string
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError!) {
    self.errorP = parseError
    NSLog("failure error: %@", parseError)
    }
}
```

Thanks

EDIT:  Added other file's code as requested.

```
//
//  GovDataRequest.swift
//  
//
//  Created by Michael Pulsifer (U.S. Department of Labor) on 6/18/14.
//  License: Public Domain
//

import Foundation

protocol GovDataRequestProtocol {
    func didCompleteWithError(errorMessage: String)
    func didCompleteWithDictionary(results: NSDictionary)
}

class GovDataRequest {

    var delegate: GovDataRequestProtocol? = nil

    var APIKey = ""
    var APIHost = ""
    var APIURL = ""
    var responseFormat = "JSON"
    var timeOut = 60.0

    init(APIKey: String, APIHost: String, APIURL:String) {
        self.APIKey = APIKey
        self.APIHost = APIHost
        self.APIURL = APIURL
    }


    func callAPIMethod (#method: String, arguments: Dictionary<String,String>) {
        // Construct the base url based on the provided information
        var url = APIHost + APIURL + "/" + method
        // Start building the query string
        var queryString = ""

        // Where appropriate, add the key
        switch APIHost {
        case "http://api.dol.gov":
            queryString = "?KEY=" + APIKey
        case "http://api.census.gov", "http://pillbox.nlm.nih.gov":
            queryString = "?key=" + APIKey
        case "http://api.eia.gov", "http://developer.nrel.gov", "http://api.stlouisfed.org", "http://healthfinder.gov":
            queryString = "?api_key=" + APIKey
        case "http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov":
            queryString = "?token=" + APIKey
        default:
            // do nothing for now
            println("doing nothing for now")
        }

        //Construct the arguments part of the query string
        for (argKey, argValue) in arguments {
            switch APIHost {
            case "http://api.dol.gov":
                // DOL's V1 API has specific formatting requirements for arguments in the query string
                switch argKey {
                case "top", "skip", "select", "orderby", "filter":
                    queryString += "&$" + argKey + "=" + argValue
                case "format", "query", "region", "locality", "skipcount":
                    queryString += "&" + argKey + "=" + argValue
                default:
                    println("nothing to see here")
                }
            case "http://go.usa.gov":
                // go.usa.gov requires that the apiKey be the 2nd argument
                if countElements(queryString) == 0 {
                    queryString += "?" + argKey + "=" + argValue + "&apiKey=" + APIKey
                } else {
                    queryString += "&" + argKey + "=" + argValue
                }
            default:
                if countElements(queryString) == 0 {
                    queryString += "?" + argKey + "=" + argValue
                } else {
                    queryString += "&" + argKey + "=" + argValue
                }
            }

        }

        //If there are arguments, append them to the url
        if countElements(queryString) > 0 {
            url += queryString
        }

        //DOT FMCSA requires that the key be placed at the end.
        if APIHost == "https://mobile.fmcsa.dot.gov" {
            if countElements(queryString) > 0 {
                url += "&webKey=" + APIKey
            } else {
                url += "?webKey=" + APIKey
            }
        }

        /*
            ASSUMPTION: data retrieved is in JSON format.
            TODO: consider situation when XML is received.
        */


            // Send the request to the API and parse
            var urlToPackage = url.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println(urlToPackage)
            var urlToSend: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlToPackage)
            var apiSessionConfiguration: NSURLSessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
            apiSessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = timeOut
            var session = NSURLSession(configuration:apiSessionConfiguration)
            var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:urlToSend)
            request.addValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField:"Accept")
            var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
                println("Task completed")
                if(error) {
                    // if there is an error in the request, print it to the console
                    self.delegate?.didCompleteWithError(error.localizedDescription)
                    //println(error.localizedDescription)
                    println("oops!")
                }
                var err: NSError?
                if self.responseFormat == "JSON" {
                    var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
                    if(err?) {
                        // If there is an error parson JSON, print it to the console
                        NSLog ("Error parsing the JSON")
                    }
                    self.delegate?.didCompleteWithDictionary(jsonResult)
                } else if self.responseFormat == "XML" {
                    // Put XML parsing code here
                    var error = NSError()
                    var xmlReader = XMLDictionary(error: error)
                    var xmlResult = xmlReader.dictionaryForXMLData(data, error: error) as NSDictionary
                    self.delegate?.didCompleteWithDictionary(xmlResult)
                }
                })
            task.resume()
    }


}
```

Comment: Please add the XML as well. It needs to be valid XML.

Comment: It's quite large.  So large, that if I included it, it would be quite obnoxious.  Here's one example that I know should work (it comes up in Chrome): http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?FcstType=digitalDWML&lat=40.501368&lon=-79.865723

Comment: It doesn't seem to have a public identifier, so it can't have a space there neither: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_Public_Identifier#Use_in_XML_and_SGML

Comment: That's where things get weird, though.  The original Objective-C code still works.

Comment: I think it even is the original Objective-C code being executed in NSXMLParser. That leads me to think that somehow the default settings are different between the one being created in Swift and the one in Objective-C. I wonder what happens if you compare the settings under Managing Parser Behavior in the debugger between the Obj-C created instance and the Swift created instance https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsxmlparser_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSXMLParser/shouldResolveExternalEntities

Comment: Neither the original Objective-C code or mine appears to call either of the setters.  Random thought: could defaults be different between the environments?  Have a lot more digging to do, especially since http://api.dol.gov/V1/DOLAgency/Agencies?KEY=2bc4aa85-4d4e-4e33-820e-5ddbc7a1c237 is giving me the error of "NSXMLParserErrorMessage=Document is empty," which to me seems bizarre.

Comment: Hmmm my best hunch is that the data that goes in is different in some way. Strings are different in Swift, perhaps somewhere it affects the input data before it goes into the parser

Comment: Yet I'm retrieving the data as NSData right from the get-go. Your thoughts a good ones, especially since Swift is still in development. As time goes on I'm left ever more stumped and wishing these older web APIs would give JDON equal support

Comment: If you would like to you could share the whole code with me and I can take a look when I have some spare time. You could also look into filing a bug to Apple, I guess they want people to start working with it and report back problems since it's a beta.